# error while reading video using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to read a video, and detect somethings based on training I did.

I am getting this error. I have went through all the possible solutions here in stackoverflow, but I couldn't solve it.

I am getting this error message.

```
error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat




import cv2
path= '..' # my path
classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier("faces.xml")
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(path+'recordedVideo.avi')
while True:
    frame = camera.read()[1]
    detections = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
    for detection in detections:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, tuple(detection[:2]), tuple(detection[:2] + detection[2:]), (255,0,0))
    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 113:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Would anyone give some hints here on how can I solve it ?

Note: I had no problem using this algorithm on one picture; The problem is probably related on how I read video

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `path+'recordedVideo.avi'` need to be something like `path+'/recordedVideo.avi'`? Or is that just a typo you did on stack overflow and not in your code?

If that's not the problem, maybe the video codec is not supported by OpenCV, could you post the codec the video is using?

Comment: This could be a comment! not an answer.  This is just a typo I did when I wanted to hide the path I used

Comment: I used the video posted in one of the example on the internet.

Comment: Maybe you haven't installed all the necessary dependencies as stated here.. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html such as libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev and so you don't have the right packages to decode the video

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec54` (if you are on a Debian based distro)